# Solace - Load-Balancing chunked messages

Tags: solace

I wish to use Solace guaranteed messaging with load balanced consumers.

Currently if I use a queue with non-exclusive access type and have multiple consumers each consumer will get a message round-robin and if a consumer should die its unacknowledged messages will forwarded to another consumer.

This is the functionality I require however due to the varying size of message payloads I may exceed the limit so need to implement chunking.

The problem now is that I have no way of guaranteeing that all the chunked messages for a single message is handled by the same consumer so that it can rebuild the original message and once built do appropriate message acknowledge.

Is there a way I achieve this with Solace.

In Kafka I can use partition keys of original message to ensure chunked messages are routed to same consumer and using complicated commit sync logic.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement your own message chunking logic within your application using features available in Solace.

This can be achieved with the use of selectors in Solace. Egress selectors enable client applications to specify which messages they are interested in receiving, as determined by the messages’ header field and property values. Following this logic, if a message needs to be chunked, you can add the same identifier property to all of the chunks in a message. The customers will bind to the non-exclusive queue with different selectors so that each consumer will only receive messages with one type of identifier.

Another feature to consider in addition to selectors is transactions. You can start a transaction with the beginning chunk of the message and only commit when the last chunk in the message is received. This way, if the consumer should die, the transaction will rollback and all chunks in the message will be returned to the queue.